# display multiple permission at once xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin Form PCL project for Android and IOS. 
Is this possible to display multiple permission at once on the screen? My App is using Location, Storage and Camera permission. From my current code, this is displaying permission popup one by one on the different page like before use of camera i display camera permission popup. As I know three permission required for my App so i want to display a single popup for all three permission.
Below is my code for storage permission.

```
public static async Task<dynamic> CheckStoragePermission()
    {
        var result = "";
        try
        {
            var Storagestatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage);
            if (Storagestatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                await Utils.CheckPermissions(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error(ex.Message, Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException), ex.Source, ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Hope someone did this before in xamarin forms, I will thank for your help for this.

Comment: Have you looked at the [permissions plugin for Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)?

Comment: `RequestPermissionAsync` takes variable number of arguments, pass all the permissions you want, and each one is prompted one after the other. Android (or even iOS) doesn't have multi permission prompt

Comment: To display a single popup for all three permissions is for apps that targeted Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower. Starting in Android 6.0 (API level 23), apps must check at run-time to see if they have permission to access a protected resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using the following code to request multiple permissions at one time:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await GetPermissions();
    }


public static async Task<bool> GetPermissions()
    {
        bool permissionsGranted = true;

        var permissionsStartList = new List<Permission>()
        {
            Permission.Location,
            Permission.LocationAlways,
            Permission.LocationWhenInUse,
            Permission.Storage,
            Permission.Camera
        };

        var permissionsNeededList = new List<Permission>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsStartList)
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionsNeededList.Add(permission);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permissionsNeededList.ToArray());

        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsNeededList)
            {
                var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
                //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                if (results.ContainsKey(permission))
                    status = results[permission];
                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted || status == PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    permissionsGranted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    permissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return permissionsGranted;
    }
```

Comment: is this possible that i can display custom message example for permission of location "App want to get your current location".

Comment: @A.Goutam, please post a new question about this.

Comment: Why app crashing ?