# Xamarin Forms throws Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException while taking photo

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to capture an image/pick up an image from gallery in Xamarin Forms app. I have installed the nuget manager > `Birdie.MediaPlugin`. During On click on the button in the Register page throws below error;

`Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details` Could someone please advise where should we add persmission in Xamarin.Forms app ?

// Register.xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="imageDisplay" />
<Button x:Name="uploadButton" 
                    Text="Upload Image" Clicked="UploadButton_Clicked"/>
```

// PlayerDetails.cs

```
public ImageSource Source { get; internal set; }
```

//Register.xaml.cs

```
PlayerDetails myDetails;

 public Register(PlayerDetails playD)
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            BindingContext = myDetails;

        }

    private async void UploadButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //myDetails.Image = new Image();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var status = await GetPermissions();

        if(status == true)
        {

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "flower1.jpg"
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

            myDetails.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                file.Dispose();
                return stream;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Permissions Denied", "Unable to take photos.", "OK");

            //On iOS you may want to send your user to the settings screen.
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
        }

    }
```

//I have split the permission function as below;

```
public static async Task<bool> GetPermissions()
    {
        bool permissionsGranted = true;

        var permissionsStartList = new List<Permission>()
    {
        Permission.Location,
        Permission.LocationAlways,
        Permission.LocationWhenInUse,
        Permission.Storage,
        Permission.Camera
    };

        var permissionsNeededList = new List<Permission>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsStartList)
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionsNeededList.Add(permission);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nice, exception! " + ex);
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permissionsNeededList.ToArray());

        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsNeededList)
            {
                var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
                //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                if (results.ContainsKey(permission))
                    status = results[permission];
                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted || status == PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    permissionsGranted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    permissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Last, exception! " + ex);
        }
        return permissionsGranted;
    }
```

Comment: there are extensive docs on this - have you read them and followed all of the steps?  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#important-permission-information

Comment: @Jason: I had go through some of the tutorials and updated my code. Now on clcik on button throws `Unhandled Exception: Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>`. I have split the permission function as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `OnClick` event code to add the permissions logic as well:

```
var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<CameraPermission>();
var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<StoragePermission>();

if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted || storageStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<CameraPermission>();
    storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<StoragePermission>();
}

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
{
    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
    return;
}

if (cameraStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted && storageStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
     var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "flower1.jpg"
    });

    if (file == null)
    return;

    await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    myDetails.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        file.Dispose();
        return stream;
    });
}
else
{
    await DisplayAlert("Permissions Denied", "Unable to take photos.", "OK");

    //On iOS you may want to send your user to the settings screen.
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
}
```

*Note:It will become a long function so I recommend breaking it up into different functions.*

Comment: Will try that and reply back soon.

Comment: I am getting red highlight for '.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<CameraPermission>' ...at lines here `var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<CameraPermission>();
            var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<StoragePermission>();`

Comment: I corrected the issue by the following link and the issue with permission has resolved now `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333745/display-multiple-permission-at-once-xamarin-forms` But during onclick on button, nothing is happening. I am emulator now. using `Android 6.0-Api 23`. So do you think i need to be connected on real device

Comment: Now during on click on button throws `Unhandled Exception:
Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>` I have updated my latest code above

Comment: Emulators don't have cameras, and some android devices don't have cameras or the cameras may be messed up, so this line takes care of that: if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)

Comment: Where are you stuck now? Place a System.Exception catchpoint to see exactly where that Timeout Exception is thrown. Also please update your code with the latest code, so I can help better?

Comment: The code above is the latest, I have connected to a android phone and not using emulator now.

Comment: Did a debug and set a break point at this line  `var status = await GetPermissions();` and it is returning `true` at this point and later it not executing the if condition `if(status==true)` it going to else part and throws the above exception.

Comment: Why did you do "if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted || status == PermissionStatus.Unknown){permissionsGranted = true;}"? How does PermissionStatus.Unknown mean that the permission was granted?